# PHP: When using explode() twice, how to auto increase

Tags: php, mysql

I was trying something but I need to explode it twice because I store 2 variables in a string. Anyways, I used a while loop but I don't understand, I use cid++, but it does not appear to increase. ANyways, here's the code.

```
              $cid = 0;
              while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
                $comment = explode("-", $row['comments']);
                $madeby = explode("///", $comment[$cid]);
                $cid++;
                echo $madeby[1];
              }
```

Comment: See [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574)

Comment: ...and [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php)

Comment: Both comments above are right. But to answer the question, you're checking `$comment[0]` on the first row, then `$comment[1]` in the second row, and so on. I don't think that's really the intention.

Comment: I think you need `[]` for `$madeby`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're setting a var and incrementing you can use it as a key for both arrays.

```
$cid = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   $comment[$cid] = explode("-", $row['comments']);
   $madeby[$cid] = explode("///", $comment[$cid]);
   echo $madeby[$cid][1];
   $cid++;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
foreach($madeby as $key=>$tempArr){
   echo '"'.$madeby[$key][0].'" by "'.$madeby[$key][1].'"<br>'; 
}
```

To see the whole array:

```
print_r($madeby);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){

    $comment = explode("-", $row['comments']);
    $cnt = count($comment);

    $madeby = array();
    for($cid=0; $cid<$cnt; $cid++){
        $madeby[] = explode("///", $comment[$cid]);
    }    
    print_r($madeby);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
 $comment = explode("-", $row['comments']);
 foreach($comment as $each_comment)
 {
  $madeby = explode("///", $each_comment);
  echo $madeby[1];
 }
}
```

or if you really want to use cid then

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    {
     $comment = explode("-", $row['comments']);
     for($cid=0;$cid<count($comment);$cid++)
     {
      $madeby = explode("///", $comment[$cid]);
      echo $madeby[1];
     }
    }
```